# 2-stage selection model with censoring: Heckman selection model with second stage censoring

Tags: proportion, tobit-regression, heckman

I am seeking to get some insights on the application of two-part Tobit-type models to a distribution with potentially selection (from 0 into +ve) *and* upper truncation (censoring of data at 100%).

The distribution of the dependent variable is shown below:

[image]

The x-axis shows share (%) of the dependent variable. There are ~50% zeros (not shown) in our data with the remainder (shown) between 1%-100%.

The distribution clearly shows censoring at 100%. In addition, the initial 'hurdle' is likely important given the number of zeros in the data (50% of observations).

We observe data for both the zeros and the continuous portion as these data have come from a survey.

Thus, it appears there is both an initial hurdle (i.e a probit) and considerable censoring at 100%. We have some reason to believe there may be selection effects but are interested in the 'drivers' of the extent of participation (1%-100%) once selection (from zero to +ve) has been accounted for.

My questions are"

1. Can I use a Heckman model where the second stage is an upper-censored 1-stage Tobit? This would mean using a Heckman model wherein the 0/1 represent 0%/+ve % respectively. The Tobit would then account for the upper bound. The Inverse Mills Ratio (IMR) is highly significant and substantive in an OLS function.
2. Or should we just use a Cragg model with the second stage being a double-bound Tobit?
3. Or should we apply a multinomial selection equation (1st stage of Heckman) with IMRs for both the zeros and for the 100% observations?

I think that option 1 is the most correct as we do not think there is a selection component for the 100% observations. But I am unsure about the validity of using a Tobit in the second stage of the Heckman model to account for a different form of censoring.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Daniel